# Find and Replace Regex across multiple files locally

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a local folder with lots of .txt files inside it, on a Win machine.
The files have all sorts of different contents.

Separately, I have a LIST of 100 x different words:

```
word 1
word 2
...
word 100
```

I am trying to do a **Find and Replace Regex** formula inside **Notepad++** (find and replace in files) to replace **ANY** of the 100 words from the list above with the word "NEW", for all the .txt files in the folder

Does anyone know how i can do this?

If there is a better way other than Notepad++ to do it, that'd be great too, but so far couldn't find another way.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do it programatically. Hint: read each file inside your folder, search the specific word on each file, replace with desired word and save that it. That's it!

Comment: I am not a good programmer unfortunately:( ; but if i can get a powershell that works, then i can use that. but i am not that good of a coder : (

Comment: You could take your word list, replace newlines with `|`, then run the command `sed -i s/[word list]/NEW/ *.txt`

Comment: @DougLasore use _Find in Files_ option in notepad++,it can easily mention find, replace ,which directory that should check and also you can use regular expression

Comment: thanks a lot to all of you for the help, really appreciate it! 

@CAustin is "sed - i.." a Linux command or can i use it on Win too? i.e. using Git Bash for instance on win

Comment: @DougLasore Windows 10 supports `sed`; not sure about earlier versions though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in 2 steps:

1. open the file that contains the words to search and do the following:

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
   - Find what: `\R(?=.)`
   - Replace with: `NEW`
   - **CHECK** *Wrap around*
   - **CHECK** *Regular expression*
   - **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
   - <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?=.)       # positive lookahead, make sure we have a character after (to prevent adding a pipe at the end of the string)
```

**Replacement:**

```
|           # a pipe character
```

### Here is an example with 9 words only to explain the process.

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
3. Copy the line with the word pipe separated.
4. Paste in the Find whatbox and add `\b(?:` at the beginning and `)\b` at the end.
5. Enter NEW in the Replace with box.
6. Give the filter (`*.txt`)
7. Give the path to the directory.
8. <kbd>Replace in Files</kbd>

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with Visual Studio Code.

Before starting, backup your files just in case you are not happy with the results.

1. Open the folder where you have the files (`File` > `Open Folder...`).
2. Open the search menu (magnifying glass) or press `Shift + Alt + F`
3. The search box will open, then:

   - Turn on Regular Expression (`.*` button)
   - Insert the pattern: `\b(word_1|word_2|word_3)\b`. In this case you have 100 words, I don't know if this input has a character limit or not. If it has a limit, do several replacements.
4. Insert the replacement text
5. In `files to include` use `*.txt` to limit the search to txt files
6. Press `Enter` and a preview will show you how these words are being replaced
7. Proceed to `Replace All` (button to the right of the replacement box) or press `Ctrl + Alt + Enter`

The search pattern `\b(word1|word2|word3)\b` will look for any word between `()` and separated by `|` (or). The `\b`s are there to ensure that the full words are matched and that they are not inside another.

[image: Find in folder]

[image]